# Capture value surounded by symbol in string

Tags: javascript, regex

Inside my strings there is values surounded by $:

```
"$FORMAT$ is invalid, please check $FILE$ file"
```

I want to take variable names between $ (for example $FORMAT$ should be - FORMAT) to compare and if they match some condition replace variable in string with some value (for example ".txt"). I tried to achive that functionality with regex:

```
/\$(\w+)\$/gi
```

But it takes $ with variable names. How can I modify my regex to make it work properly? Thanks!

Comment: i think that you shouldn't use $

Comment: Ok, what should be better?

Comment: Your regex will work if you replace it by `$1`.

Comment: every char that isn't one of the most used in many technologies, try to use pipe |

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/W4wmMl/1

Comment: @Tushar is right: the regex is fine already, just replace by `$1` and you're done (your current matches will be $FORMAT$ and FORMAT). Alternatively, you may want to use positive lookaheads to avoid matching $, but you still will multiple matches whatsoever.

Comment: What condition? Please post a real life scenario. Check [this JSFiddle, too](https://jsfiddle.net/qoj87uq5/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/\$(.+?)\$/gi` should work well in your case.

Comment: When you use either  String.prototype.match or RegExp.prototype.exec, the right name is in the item of index #1 of the matched result, but not #0.

Comment: It's almost the same. The problem with that regexes that they capture variables with $ symbols.

Comment: Yes, the answer is in the comment just above yours.